# Apache2: How to set Environment Variable inside External Auth Script

Tags: apache, authentication, unix, environment-variables, apache2

I'm using this plugin to validate a Personal Access Token of my users:
https://github.com/phokz/mod-auth-external

The username does not matter, I'm validating the PAT against an external service.
This external service is returning a UserId & Role.

Now I want to be able to set the userId & Role as an environment variable **inside** the external authenticator and later use these two in the CGI Script that Apache2 will call for a dedicated route.

I've tried the following, but the environment variables are always empty. Is it possible to set from the external auth a value? How can I communicate back to apache2 otherwise?
***- Keep in mind that the below is a minimal example to show and focus on the issue itself -***

**Two Simple External Authenticator Script (Both not setting the env)**

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl
use Env;

$ENV{USER}="TESTUSER1";
$ENV{USERID}="TESTUSER2";
$ENV{ROLE}="ADMIN";
$ENV{REMOTE_USER}="TESTUSER3";

exit 0;
```

```bash
#! /bin/sh

export USER="USER1"
export USERID="USER2"
export ROLE="USER3"
export REMOTE_USER="USER4"

exit 0
```

**script.pm**

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl
die "The user '$ENV{USER}', '$ENV{USERID}', '$ENV{ROLE}', '$ENV{REMOTE_USER}' has no access!";
```

**apache2 config for route /**

```xml
<VirtualHost *:80>
    SetEnv USERID

    AddExternalAuth pwauth "/usr/local/scripts/authenticator.sh"
    SetExternalAuthMethod pwauth pipe

    ScriptAlias / /usr/local/scripts/script.pm/

    <Location />
        Options +ExecCGI +FollowSymLinks +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
        AllowOverride None
        order allow,deny
        Allow from all
        AuthType Basic
        AuthName "Restricted Content"
        AuthBasicProvider external
        AuthExternal pwauth
        Require valid-user
    </Location>

    AddHandler cgi-script .pm
</VirtualHost>
```